# PIC16F887 PORT won't work with XC8 C compiler

Tags: c, embedded, pic, microchip, xc8

I'm pretty new to PIC programming and I'm trying to use C (compiled with Microchip's XC8 Free in [MPLABX](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/)) to make a simple "Input to Output" program.
 The problem I'm having is that the RA2, RA3 and RA5 input pins are just not working when programming in C.
It's probably not a hardware problem, because when programming in [Ladder](http://cq.cx/ladder.pl) those pins work just fine.
I've searched around on the internet for a while and couldn't find anyone with the same problem yet.

The program I'm trying to burn onto the PIC is as follows:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

#include <xc.h>

// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = ON // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
//END CONFIG

int main()
{
  TRISB = 0x00;
  TRISE = 0x00;
  TRISC = 0x00;
  TRISD = 0xFF;
  TRISA = \
          _TRISA_TRISA2_MASK |\
          _TRISA_TRISA3_MASK |\
          _TRISA_TRISA4_MASK |\
          _TRISA_TRISA5_MASK;
  PORTD = 0x00;
  PORTA = 0x00;
  PORTB = 0x00;
  PORTE = 0x00;
  PORTC = 0x00;

  while(1){
    PORTB = PORTA;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I do get an output on PORTB if I set RA4 to HIGH, but not for RA2, RA3 nor RA5. I believe this might be a problem with the configuration bits or something, but I'm not sure.

Hardware being used:

- Microchip PIC16F887
- [FLEXiS Plus Board](http://smartradio.com.br/pic/FlexisPlus/2-Manual%20FLEXIS%20Plus.pdf) (sorry no english manual, but in page 8 and 9 there are board schematics)

Software being used:

- [Microchip MPLABX IDE](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/)
- [TinyBootloader](http://www.etc.ugal.ro/cchiculita/software/tinyblddownload.htm)

Comment: Note: there is no need to escape newline (this is not Python). Proper indentation is enough and better to read (easier to identify the operator `|`).

Comment: @Olaf thanks for your suggestion, but I'd rather keep the escapes as for me it makes it explicit that the line didn't finish there. It's down to personal preference though

Comment: It is - partly and I will not comment further after this last comment. just think about the following: It is harder to read with the backslashes and another programmer reading your code (as here) will at least have to think for a moment, possibly breaking his flow of reading. Oh, and many company coding standards do not allow this (partly for the reasons above). Recommended practice for Python, for instance is to parenthesise, if possible to avoid backspashes. Note this psychology, not just a personal preference. - As I stated, just please think about it; no need to comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that those specific pins are also Analog Inputs for the ADC Module, you have to configure them to be digital I/O to use them. Try setting `ANSEL = 0x00` at the beginning of your program.

You can see in the datasheet that the default value of `ANSEL` on POR is `0xFF` so all analog pins are configured as analog inputs by default.

Comment: That is correct sir, thanks a lot. One more question, i want RA0 and RA1 to be analog inputs, for that i need to set `ANSEL = 0x03`?

Answer (score 0):

To use pins for analog input, you should set the relevant bits in both the ANSEL and TRISx registers.